# Properly formatting date for display in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have date like

$scope.newd =   '2015-08-11 12:36:33.649';

Coming from backend JSON. In my UI i want to display like 11/08/2015.

I was using `Date.parse($scope.newd)` to convert and then format. But this does not work in FF. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### for cross-browser compatibility,

date string is converted with "-" to "/" removing time,

```
 $scope.oldDate = '2015-08-11 12:36:33.649';
 $scope.newD= $filter('date')(new Date($scope.oldDate.split(" ")[0].replace(/-/g,"/")), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Refer this link : 
http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html

Answer (score 1):

You can apply filter on controller layer like

```
    $scope.oldDate = '2015-08-11 12:36:33.649';
   $scope.newD= $filter('date')(new Date(parseInt($scope.oldDate.substr(6))), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

You have to inject $filter in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

## Filters

Use the date filter in your html like this

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}
```

read the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

## Example

Here is an example of a date input that is shown after it has been through the filter.

```
<p>
    <label>Select a date</label>
    <input type="date" id="date" ng-model="datevalue" />
</p>

<p> {{ datevalue | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   Date.prototype.today = function () { 
                            return ((this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate() +"/"+(((this.getMonth()+1) < 10)?"0":"") + (this.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ this.getFullYear();
                        }

    var newDate = new Date($scope.newd );
                        var date =newDate.today();          
              $scope.newd = newDate.today();
```